# How can I find who pushed a tag(s) to BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

We deleted some unwanted tags from our bitbucket repository and (so we thought) all our local repositories, but obviously we have missed one repo somewhere as they keep getting re-pushed.

How can I find out who is pushing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find that easily (maybe BitBucket support has some log), but, as a workaround, you could add a [post-receive hook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks) (like [a POST one](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/POST+hook+management)) in order for another git client to be notified of any push.

That git client could check if tags were pushed, and, if those tags are unwanted, push back their deletion.